# Preventing horizontal drag scrolling on a 100% width page

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow, css-animations

I've got a page design that uses CSS keyframes to make a `min-height: 100%` `<section>` element containing page content slide in from the right. *Once the element has animated to its final position, it is possible to "drag-scroll" the page horizontally by selecting and dragging the text, which I want to avoid*.

Both the `<html>` and `<body>` elements are set to `overflow-x: hidden;`, which works for preventing scrollbars but still allows scrolling functionality. I do need users to be able to scroll the `<section>` element vertically.

I'm assuming the problem is caused by the initial `translateX` value in the keyframe animation, but I'm not sure how to prevent the horizontal drag scrolling.

Here's [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hEKPD/10/embedded/result/) demonstrating the problem.

I appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a javascript solution? How is the following:

```
function bindEvent(e, eventName, callback) {
    if(e.addEventListener) // new browsers
        e.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
    else if(e.attachEvent) // IE
        e.attachEvent('on'+ eventName, callback);
};

bindEvent(document.body, 'scroll', function(e) {
    document.body.scrollLeft = 0;
});
```